# Set keyboard shortcut in Firefox extensions preferences

Tags: firefox-addon

I have developed a Firefox Extension that uses keyboard shortcuts. This is the way I implement them right now in my main XUL-file.

```
<keyset>
    <key id="myExtension-key-1" modifiers="alt" keycode="VK_RIGHT" oncommand="myExtension(event);"/>
</keyset>
```

This works but I would like to let the users pick their own keyboard shortcut (including modifier keys) in the extension preferences. I already have options.xul and a basic understanding for how I should work with preferences in my extension.

I have searched but haven't really found anything on this subject. Any guidance in the right direction would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to manipulate the `keyset` programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few references for keyboard shortcut extension development:

- [pref-keys.js](http://svn.openkomodo.com/openkomodo/view/openkomodo/trunk/src/chrome/komodo/content/pref/pref-keys.js)
- [pref-keys.p.xul](http://svn.openkomodo.com/openkomodo/view/openkomodo/trunk/src/chrome/komodo/content/pref/pref-keys.p.xul)
- [keybindings.p.xml](http://svn.openkomodo.com/openkomodo/view/openkomodo/trunk/src/chrome/komodo/content/keybindings/keybindings.p.xml)
- [keybindings.p.js](http://svn.openkomodo.com/openkomodo/view/openkomodo/trunk/src/chrome/komodo/content/keybindings/keybindings.p.js)